# zf2 : module with pluggable plugins approach

Tags: php, model-view-controller, plugins, zend-framework2, factory-pattern

I have some basic ZF2 knowledge for creating normal projects. Now I want to create a module which is extendable by user community by creating plugins for its features.

I have created basic architecture like

```
ModuleName
    src
        Service
            MyService.php
        Factory
            Fun1Factory.php
            Fun2Factory.php
        Plugins
            Fun1Plugins
                PluginA.php
                PluginB.php
            Fun2Plugins
                PluginC.php
                PluginD.php
```

I have created two factory classes ( not from zf2 factoryinterface) for handling each type of functionality like Fun1Factory.php & Fun2Factory.php. They both are registered in module.config.php through invokables.

```
'invokables' => array (
    'Fun1Factory' => 'ModuleName\Factory\Fun1Factory',
    'Fun2Factory' => 'ModuleName\Factory\Fun2Factory',
)
```

Now MyService actually calling them with arguments for specific plugins. Like below.

```
$fun1Factory = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Fun1Factory');
$fun1Factory->setSettings($settings['fun1']);
$this->fun1Plugin = $fun1Factory->getPlugin();
$this->fun1Plugin->init();

$fun2Factory = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Fun2Factory');
$fun2Factory->setSettings($settings['fun2']);
$this->fun2Plugin = $fun2Factory->getPlugin();
$this->fun2Plugin->init();
```

So code can be called like that

```
$service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModuleName\Service\MyService');
$service->init(array('fun1' => 'pluginA', 'fun2' => 'pluginD'));
```

I earlier built similar using basic MVC + Factory Pattern. But I don't know how it should be build into ZF2. ZF2 give factory interface, but that look like a very similar to autoload some service/controllers. If their are any guide how to create a such module ?

UPDATE : I can do factory code also in MyService class. But I am thinking of "ZF2 WAY" to doing this.

MORE DETAILS : I have update question wtih more details. The closest I found at https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/zend-framework-2-getting-closer-with-pluginmanager/ . But I still need to dynamically register plugin to factory instead of statically in there like below.

```
protected $invokableClasses = array(
    //represent invokables key
    'xls' => 'Tutorial\Plugin\Xls',
    'pdf' => 'Tutorial\Plugin\Pdf'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want plugin creators having to modify the service_manager at the module.config.php then you have two options:

An option is creating a Factory for MyService that will look for its dependencies in those plugin folders.

Other option would be creating an invoke method for MyService passing the plugin as an argument and then you create the plugin instance.

But the way zf2 works is using module.config.php to register instances in the service_manager. So if the plugin creators can use the service_manager will be better.

[UPDATE]

Zend FactoryInterface is used for creating instances which have dependencies, so those dependencies are created or extracted from the ServiceManager and then they are injected via constructor to the instance the factory has been created for.

In your case your plugin developers would have to create factories for their plugins and register those factories in the service_manager. If they didn't then you need a way to know if a plugin has dependencies.

Hope this helps

Ismael Trascastro

Comment: Zend FactoryInterface is used for creating instances which have dependencies, so those dependencies are created or extracted from the ServiceManager and then they are injected via constructor to the instance the factory has been created for.

Comment: The closest I found at https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/zend-framework-2-getting-closer-with-pluginmanager/ . But I still need to dynamically register plugin to factory instead of statically.

Comment: Modifying a little the samsonasik approach, you can have your own key in the module.config.php to register plugins with their own factories.